# How can I execute more than one expression in a list comprehension in Python?

Tags: python, list, tuples, list-comprehension

Firstly, I understand that this *is not a best practice*. However, this is for a coding challenge where the aim is to make the shortest code possible. Here is the challenge.[image]

The challenge itself is quite easy to solve, as illustrated by the below code:

```
def solution(a, b, n):
    op = []
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        op += [a * b]
        a += 1
        b += 1
    return sum(op)
```

However, I want to make this code as short as possible, and to do so, I wanted to use a list comprehension and lambda, like so:

```
sol = lambda a,b,n: [(op+=[a*b, a+=1, b+=1) for i in range(1, n+1)]
```

As you can see, in this comprehension. I need to append an element to the end of the list, **and** increment a and b. In another Stack Overflow post, I saw that someone had used a tuple to achieve this, however, when I try this, I get the error

```
sol = lambda a,b,n: [(a+=1,b+=1) for i in range(1,n+1)]
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can I fix this? Any other suggestions are also welcome

Comment: Why do you need the list? Just increment the total variable by the product of the two numbers.

Comment: @Barmar Can you give an example?

Comment: Maybe you should try http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 3):

There's no need for the list. And you don't need to increment the variables with `+=`, use the `range()` function to get a sequence of incrementing numbers. You can then use `zip()` to pair up the two sequences of numbers.

```
def solution(a, b, n):
    return sum(a * b for a, b in zip(range(a, a+n), range(b, b+n)))
```